# Ubuntu Server 16.04 - installed ubuntu-desktop but getting no screens error (ee)

Tags: server, 16.04

As per the title, I've installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 and installed ubuntu-desktop, but when I try to `startx` in to the server I get the following error

```
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE) 
(EE)
```

The server is based remotely with no screen attached..

Can anyone give advice?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To clarify: are you connecting to this computer via SSH? If so, what operating system is on the local computer?

Comment: If you have no screens attached, you need to forward your xsession over ssh see this post on how to do that: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12755/how-to-forward-x-over-ssh-from-ubuntu-machine

Comment: What are you wanting to do on the remote system that requires a full desktop UI? There is more than likely a sleeker and more secure solution to what you want to achieve

Comment: I am connecting via SSH - I'm using terminal on OS X El Capitan

Comment: I believe you'll need to install XQuartz on your local (Mac) machine, then you can follow one of the many tutorials available online for SSH with X forwarding with XQuartz. I'm not sure if this plays nice with Ubuntu's compositing manager or not, but I believe it should work for most applications

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164888/fatal-server-error-ee-no-screens-foundee-at-any-tty and https://askubuntu.com/questions/991697/xserver-error-no-screens-foundee but neither of those questions have answers. :(

Comment: Also might be related https://askubuntu.com/questions/457850/x-server-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-14-04-what-may-be-happening