# Xserver error: no screens found(EE)

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I'm a newb to all of this and have no idea how to fix this problem. 
I'm trying to use Xorg on ubuntu 16.04 on my AWS server by running these commands.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y xserver-xorg mesa-utils
sudo nvidia-xconfig -a --use-display-device=None --virtual=1280x1024
```

reboot and then

```
sudo /usr/bin/X :0 &
export DISPLAY=:0
```

but when I run "sudo /usr/bin/X :0 &", the error below shows

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-99:~$ sudo /usr/bin/X :0 & [1] 1794
ubuntu@ip-172-31-12-99:~$

X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux ip-172-31-12-99 4.4.0-1044-aws #53-Ubuntu SMP
Mon Dec 11 13:49:57 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-1044-aws 
root=UUID=3e13556e-d28d-407b-bcc6-97160eafebe1 ro console=tty1 console=ttyS0
Build Date: 13 October 2017  01:57:05PM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.7 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
   (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
   (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.

(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Jan  3 02:52:56 2018
(==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support at http://wiki.x.org for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Don't run x with sudo

Comment: do you mean I should run just `/usr/bin/X :0 &` instead?
this gives
`/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap: Only console users are allowed to run the X server`

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ? X over ssh ? manage your server , there are web front ends for that. See http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/09/26/how-to-fix-x-user-not-authorized-to-run-the-x-server-aborting/

Comment: X over ssh sounds right. Anyways, solved it by updating ubuntu version ty for answering!

Comment: @jun - which ubuntu version did you update to?

Comment: @Jun can you provide your solution so others can learn from it?

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164888/fatal-server-error-ee-no-screens-foundee-at-any-tty and https://askubuntu.com/questions/793679/ubuntu-server-16-04-installed-ubuntu-desktop-but-getting-no-screens-error-ee but no answers.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/457850/x-server-doesnt-work-on-ubuntu-14-04-what-may-be-happening maybe?