# Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE) at any tty

Tags: 18.04, xorg, display, display-resolution, tty

I want to create a "virtual display" to use another display resolution.

I've opened any tty from tty2 to tty6 and tried this:

```
sudo startx -- :1
```

... but always I got:

```
xauth: (stdin):2:  unknown command "f86ae7809cf17138ea28ef7a7e32d2bb"


X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux feli-pc 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic root=UUID=366115be-a8f8-4d07-8c74-1bfb4756fd6b ro acpi_osi=Windows i8042.reset i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 noplymouth video=SVIDEO-1:d
Build Date: 03 June 2019  08:10:35AM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Sat Aug 10 23:17:57 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
**Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)** 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

I've also tried:

```
Xorg -configure :1


X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux feli-pc 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-55-generic root=UUID=366115be-a8f8-4d07-8c74-1bfb4756fd6b ro acpi_osi=Windows i8042.reset i915.preliminary_hw_support=1 noplymouth video=SVIDEO-1:d
Build Date: 03 June 2019  08:10:35AM
xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/felipe/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Sat Aug 10 23:49:17 2019
(EE) 
(EE) Backtrace:
(EE) 0: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xorg_backtrace+0x4d) [0x55fac2088abd]
(EE) 1: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55fac1ed0000+0x1bc859) [0x55fac208c859]
(EE) 2: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x7f1680adf000+0x12890) [0x7f1680af1890]
(EE) 3: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55fac1ed0000+0xb231b) [0x55fac1f8231b]
(EE) 4: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (xf86BusProbe+0x9) [0x55fac1f5a229]
(EE) 5: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (InitOutput+0x7f1) [0x55fac1f68e71]
(EE) 6: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (0x55fac1ed0000+0x56cd3) [0x55fac1f26cd3]
(EE) 7: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f168070fb97]
(EE) 8: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg (_start+0x2a) [0x55fac1f10b8a]
(EE) 
(EE) Segmentation fault at address 0x50
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/felipe/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I don't know how I can proceed

BTW I've Nvidia and Intel graphics and I'm using nvidia (proprietary) and i915 drivers respectively

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am running into a similar issue.

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/991697/xserver-error-no-screens-foundee and https://askubuntu.com/questions/793679/ubuntu-server-16-04-installed-ubuntu-desktop-but-getting-no-screens-error-ee but unfortunately no answers.