# x11vnc pauses for 10 seconds on initial connection on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, lightdm, vnc

I'm trying to use `x11vnc` on ubuntu 18.04 headless nvidia GPU server.

I finally made it work with `lightdm`, but there is a initial freeze time problem on the connection that's not happen with ubuntu 16.04.

As I checked the `x11vnc` log, it shows 10 seconds delay from `useCopyRect` to `client_set_net` every time. While the delay, key and mouse events are ignored although the display is shown. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
sudo /usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -noxdamage -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -shared -rfbport 5900 -rfbauth /home/$USER/.vnc/passwd
```

```
29/08/2019 17:59:33 Using tight encoding for client 192.168.1.5
29/08/2019 17:59:33 client useCopyRect: 192.168.1.5 -1
29/08/2019 17:59:43 client_set_net: 192.168.1.5  10.0103
29/08/2019 17:59:52 non-existent cursor: which=12
```

### Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04 x64
- x11vnc: 0.9.13 lastmod: 2011-08-10
- lightdm 1.26.0

Comment: It happens with `gdm3` too.

Answer (score 0):

It's been fixed with these command to fix dns bug with 18.04. I didn't think it'd been related.

```
ls -l /etc/resolv.conf
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo reboot
```